# Detecting "loading request" in Google App Engine Python

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to make sure some code is initialized on a GAE instance when it is spun up. Is there a way to detect in the code that the request is a "loading request"?

I tried adding the initialization code to my warmup handler but it does not seem that warmup is guaranteed to be called. I also tried giving each service in my application a single idle instance to increase the chance of warmup being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this answer is written with the python 2.7 standard environment in mind, I'm not sure if something equivalent would be possible for all other languages/runtimes and how it'd work.

Indeed, the warm-up requests, if configured, are only effective if there is already at least one instance running for the service, which isn't always the case.

You could place the desired init code in the main service file which declares your service's app - that code is only executed when the service app is initialized, which happens exactly once per instance lifetime, regardless of the request being a loading or a warm-up one.

Something along these lines:

```
import ...

def my_desired_init_function():
    pass  # replace with what you need to do

my_desired_init_function()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(...)
```